# mysql - Issues with results of SUM once a refernce table is joined

Tags: mysql

Good Morning,

I am running into an issue with a query.  I am attempting to do a sum of a column across a range of UTC time.  When I query only the source table with the exact UTC values it is working as expected.  Once I add a join a scheduling table add some further details the results are incorrect.  Below are the queries and table structures that I am using.  Any help would be appreciated.

Query 1:

```
select logid,SUM(ti_availtime) as "Total Avail TIme" 
from status
where logid = 12345 
and  status.starttime_utc 
between 1528070400 and 1528102800
group by logid

logid   Total Avail Time
12345   20106
```

Table Structure for status table:

```
Date    Logid   Starttime_utc   Ti_availtime    Interval
2018-06-04  12345   1528070400  106 30
2018-06-04  12345   1528070401  5000    30
2018-06-04  12345   1528070402  5000    30
2018-06-04  12345   1528102800  10000   30
```

**NOTE: The UTC values (1528070401, 1528070402) are just examples***

Table structure for schedule:

```
Date    Logid   Name    Starttime_utc   Stoptime_utc
2018-06-04  12345   John Smith  1528070400  1528102800
```

Query 2:

```
select schedule.Analyst, SUM(status.ti_availtime) 
from status
join schedule on status.logid = schedule.logid
where schedule.logid = 30120 and  status.starttime_utc between schedule.starttime_utc and schedule.starttime_utc 
group by vqschedule.row_date
```

Result:

```
Analyst Total Avail Time
John Smith  1351027
```

Answer (score 2):

Fully agreed with @jspcal and one more thing in 1st query you project status.logid but in 2nd project schedule.Analyst,  I just write the full query

```
select status.logid, SUM(status.ti_availtime) 
from status
join schedule on status.logid = schedule.logid
where schedule.logid = 30120 and  status.starttime_utc between schedule.starttime_utc and schedule.stoptime_utc
group by status.logid
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query groups by `status.logid` while the second groups by `schedule.row_date`. And should this reference `schedule.stoptime_utc` at the end time:

```
status.starttime_utc between schedule.starttime_utc and schedule.starttime_utc
```